# How can I render the nested infos from products.productId?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, crud

How can I render the **title** and **img** of under the **product.productId** and throw it to the table?

I also tried to store the recenttransaction inside another state and then map it, but it still received the latest one. How can I store the projected information and throw it to the table down below.

So this is what I received.

```
     {
        "_id": "6361f27e499c60ef9ddb147c",
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": {
                    "_id": "6360d7868044f3048e59bd8c",
                    "title": "shade",
                    "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tua-ecom.appspot.com/o/1667291013451%5Bobject%20File%5D?alt=media&token=ea7fe952-6330-44fd-8b21-8fdc84ceb7d2"
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "sellerId": "6360d4d5bd860240e258c582",
                "_id": "6361f27e499c60ef9ddb147d"
            }
        ],
        "amount": 10,
        "location": "gym",
    },
```

In this image, I can successfully render all information except the products.productId

[image: Sample Image]
[image]

So instead of rendering shade, I'm currently rendering the latest product added.

```
const [recentTransaction, setRecentTransaction] = useState([])
const [myProductTitle, setmyProductTitle] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const getStats = async () =>{
        const res = await userRequest.get(`/order/recent/${id}`)
        res.data.map((item) => {
            item.products.map((i) => {
                setmyProductTitle(i.productId)
            })
        })
        setRecentTransaction(res.data)
        setLoading(false)
    }   
getStats()
},[id])
```

This is how I render the table

```
 {recentTransaction.map((recent) => (
          <TableRow key={recent._id}>
               <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                          {recent._id}
               </TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{recent.userId.firstname} 
                  {recent.userId.lastname} 
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">{recent.userId.studentId}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">
                     <Box sx={{display: 'flex', alingItems:'center'}}>
                         <Typography mr={1}>{myProductTitle.title}</Typography>
                         <Box component="img" sx={{width: '50px'}} src{myProductTitle.img}/>
                     </Box>
                  </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">₱ {recent.amount}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left" sx={{display:'flex', alignItems:'center', borderRadius: '5px'}}>
                    <Typography sx={{padding:1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
                             {recent.status}
                     </Typography>
           </TableCell>
         </TableRow>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you need an iteration inside the table cell since `products` is an array, so for every element inside, print inside that cell the list of product along with their titles, images and ids.

Something like this

```
<TableCell align="left">
  {recent.products.map(product => (
    <Box sx={{display: 'flex', alingItems:'center'}}>
      <Typography mr={1}>{product.productId.title}</Typography>
      <Box component="img" sx={{width: '50px'}} src{product.productId.img}/></Box>
      <span>{product.productId._id}</span>
    </Box>
  )}
 </TableCell>
```